# Проблема отправки письма на почту через Nodemailer (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-native

Работаю с Node.js с Nodemailer, проблема заключается в том что при отправке письма на почту получаю ошибку в консоли и лист не отправляется. Шаблон в программу я взял здесь https://nodemailer.com/about/
В auth использовал свой тестовый аккаунт.

И в результате ошибка этого рода Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 64.233.162.108:465
Help!!! Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю с такими вопросами лучше обращаться в github Issues необходимого модуля.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сформировать подключение таким образом:

```js
createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: ************,
                pass: ************
            }
```

Если данный способ не будет работать то вероятнее всего у вас на учетной записи google заблокирован доступ к небезопасным приложениям. отключить блокировку можно тут : https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

- Небезопасными приложениями считаются приложения не поддерживающие двухфакторную аутентификацию.

Answer (score 0):

При вызове sendMail вы передаете from: 'Andrew'.
Вы должны так же передавать адрес почты, с которой отправляете письмо, об этом написано в документации: https://nodemailer.com/about/

Пример

```
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
 from: 'Andrew <mail@example.com>',
 ...
});
```